# Using different putch() function in a library

Tags: pic, c, microchip, software

I'm writing a C library for PIC18 microcontrollers that will communicate with the [ESP8266](http://www.electrodragon.com/w/ESP8266) chip over the UART bus. I would like to use the `printf()` function to send formatted strings to the chip.

In XC8, `printf()` uses the function `putch()` which the user should define as output. This way, the user can decide whether to use UART, LCD, ... for stdout.

This gives me a problem. In the library I want to use `printf()` which relies on `putch()`, but I can't (shouldn't) declare `putch()` in the library because that would give a conflict when a user wants to use the ESP8266 in combination with an LCD for which he already defined `putch()`. How can I solve this problem?

I could use `sprintf()` to temporarily store the string in the memory and then write my own code to write this byte by byte to the ESP, but I'd rather not because of memory and time inefficiency.

I could also roll my own `esp8266_printf()` with limited functionality and use that instead, but that doesn't feel that neat either.

Is there a clean(er) solution for this?

Comment: **Note:** this may seem like pure programming, but this putch-trick is not standard C, and as such this question isn't standard programming, and asks for a PIC-tuned answer.

Comment: There's no `fprintf()` available?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams no, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom PUTCH that decides at run time what to do with the byte.  This would be based on a global setting you maintain.  You'd change the global setting to route characters to wherever you want them to go at the time.  One of them can be a customer's routine, although it would have to be called something other than PUTCH.

Comment: Thanks! That would work, but with long strings, wouldn't have checking this global setting in every putch() call quite an impact on time efficiency?

Comment: Checking one boolean an if'ing on its value should not tale much time compared to the writing to a UART or LCD.

Comment: @Camil: As Wouter said, the extra check and branch will be minimal.  The larger overhead is the nested subroutine call and the passing of arguments, saving of state, etc.  If you're really worried about this, write your special PUTCH in assembler.  That way it can do the test very quickly, and avoid most of the overhead of another layer of subroutine.  For example, it can GOTO the target subroutine, which will then return to the caller of PUTCH.  You have to look at how your compiler does subroutine linkage very carefully, but if done right the extra layer should only be a few cycles.

Comment: Alright, in that case I'll just go this way and look at it again if it gets slow. Thank you!